# Uniform convergence to the max function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_1,f_2:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two differentiable functions on a open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f$ their pointwise maximum, i.e. $f(x):=max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}$ for every $x\in U$.

The function $f$ can be non differentiable, but it's possible to approximate it by differentiable functions for example by defining, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}log(e^{nf_1(x)}+e^{nf_2(x)})$, then $f_n$ will pointwise converge to $f$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Will $f_n$ also converge to $f$ **uniformly** for $n\rightarrow \infty$ in general? If not, under which additional conditions is it possible?

Comment: You are using $n$ in two different senses here.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subset $U_2$ of $U$ where $f_2 > f_1.$ The $\max$ function here is just $f_2.$ Now

$$\frac{1}{n}\ln (e^{nf_2} + e^{nf_1}) = \frac{1}{n}\ln (e^{nf_2}) + \frac{1}{n}\ln (1 + e^{n(f_1-f_2)}).$$

On the right the first summand is just $f_2.$ Because $f_1-f_2 < 0$ on $U_2,$ the second summand has the form $(1/n)\ln (1+u),$ where $0< u < 1.$ Thus on $U_2$ we have

$$|\frac{1}{n}\ln (e^{nf_2} + e^{nf_1})-f_2| < \frac{1}{n}.$$

So we have uniform convergence on $U_2.$ Similar arguments apply to $U_1 = \{f_1> f_2\}$ and $U_0 = \{f_1 = f_2\}.$ This gives your desired uniform convergence on all of $U.$